# TypeError: _this2.handleSave is not a function

Tags: reactjs

index.jsx:20 Uncaught TypeError: _this2.handleSave is not a function

React newbie here and I am trying to save events that are called to mongodb, any help would be appreciated

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Button from "../Buttons/Save";
require('dotenv').config()

class Events extends Component {
  state = {
    style: {
      height: 200,
      width: 200
    }
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <img style={this.state.style} src={this.props.url} alt="" />
        <p>Event: {this.props.name}</p>
        <p>
          <a href={this.props.link}>See Event</a>
        </p>
        <Button handleSave={() => this.handleSave()} />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Button component code below

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Save extends Component {
  state = {};
  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.props.handleSave}>Save</button>;
  }
}

export default Save;
```

Comment: You have not define your function.Can you show your Button component code. Thanks

Comment: added into the edit @SundarBan

Answer (score 0):

You have not define your function above render function in Events Component.

```
handleSave() {
    alert('ok');
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
handleSave = () => {console.log('handled save')}

<Button handleSave={this.handleSave} />
```

It seems you haven't done anything with handleSave(). You're just calling it, without defining it.

Comment: Not sure how to define it which is the issue I'm running into

Comment: What is handleSave() suppose to do. Define it as you would any other function first.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Thanks!

Comment: Edited my post. Sorry guys, first time posting here on SO!